# Installation of Seqminer

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install a package called "seqminer" in Rstudio on windows platform. Seqminer is a pre-requisite of another package that I want to install. But I am getting the following error

```
install.packages("seqminer")  Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ghaffar/R/R-3.4.2/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation seqminer    8.0    8.9              TRUE

installing the source package ‘seqminer’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/seqminer_8.9.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4147622 bytes (4.0 MB) downloaded 4.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'seqminer' ...
** package 'seqminer' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386 Error in .shlib_internal(args) :    C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined
* removing 'C:/Users/g/R/R-3.4.2/library/seqminer' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘seqminer’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in   ‘C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSo2XeN\downloaded_packages’
```

I previously installed the package on another account onedrive and it worked fine. Cant figure out what the problem is now. Any help would be highly highly appreciated!. Thankyou.

Comment: It is telling you that you don’t have correct  C++ compiler. Why not use the binary version?

Comment: You should update your R version. v3.4.2 is 6 years old.

Comment: @IRTFM from where can I download the binary version? Can it be compiled using RStudio on windows?

Comment: I have the package installed in another onedrive. Is it possible to call that package from another drive in Rstudio?

Comment: Update R, migrate your existing library of contributed packages to the current library directory, run `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)`and install from CRAN. (Rstudio does not possess compilers itself. These processes may require that your updates be done outside Rstudio)